# Color Discrepancy Between OpenCV and Photoshop Hue Adjustments

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, colors, photoshop

[image: 1]

**Problem:**
I'm encountering an issue with color while trying to apply a selected hue value into some image data using OpenCV.
After applying the hue value **+50**, the output color doesn't resemble what I see in Photoshop when I check its `+50` result.

- The first screenshot shows the **original** image without applying the hue value.
- The second screenshot displays the image with a `+50` hue value in **Photoshop**.
- The third screenshot shows the image with a `+50` hue value using the **OpenCV code**.
   (*as displayed in:* **ImGui**).

**Question:**
How can I adjust the code to make the image appear similar to the one adjusted with a **+50** hue value in Photoshop?

In the code below, **currentImage** contains the image data in `CV::Mat` format, and **hueFactor** represents the applied hue value, which is **+50**.

I've implemented the following function:

```
cv::Mat apply_hue_for_data(cv::Mat &currentImage, float hueFactor) { 

// Create the output image with the same size and type as the current 
image cv::Mat outputImage = currentImage.clone();

// Separate the alpha channel
std::vector<cv::Mat> channels(4);
cv::split(outputImage, channels);
cv::Mat alpha = channels[3];

// Convert the image from BGR to HSV
cv::cvtColor(outputImage, outputImage, cv::COLOR_BGRA2BGR);
cv::cvtColor(outputImage, outputImage, cv::COLOR_BGR2HSV);

// Loop through the rows
for (int y = 0; y < outputImage.rows; ++y) {
    // Loop through the columns
    for (int x = 0; x < outputImage.cols; ++x) {
        // Retrieve the pixel value
        cv::Vec3b &pixelValue = outputImage.at<cv::Vec3b>(y, x);

        // Adjust the hue value
        int hue = static_cast<int>(pixelValue[0]) + static_cast<int>(hueFactor * 179.0f);
        
        // Ensure the hue value wraps around correctly within the 0-179 range
        hue = hue % 180;
        if (hue < 0) {
            hue += 180;
        }
        pixelValue[0] = static_cast<uchar>(hue);
    }
}

// Convert the image back to BGR
cv::cvtColor(outputImage, outputImage, cv::COLOR_HSV2BGR);

// Merge the alpha channel back
std::vector<cv::Mat> bgrChannels;
cv::split(outputImage, bgrChannels);
std::vector<cv::Mat> bgraChannels = {bgrChannels[0], bgrChannels[1], bgrChannels[2], alpha};
cv::merge(bgraChannels, outputImage);

// Return the modified image data
return outputImage;

}
```

Any help please?
I have tried applying the hue value for the image data by using the above code, but after applying the hue value, the color doesn't resemble what I see in Photoshop.

Comment: I've googled that `Photoshop` stores hue as `‑180 to +180`. OpenCV stores it as `0 to 179`. So your 50 in `OpenCV` is like 100 in `Photoshop`

Comment: That would be my bet as well. People always get tripped up by OpenCV's mapping of hues into `uint8` (halving the angle in degrees). a value of `360` simply doesn't fit in an `uint8`, so *some* mapping has to happen. -- what's with the tags? this isn't related to OpenGL/SDL/imgui. your question's code is entirely OpenCV and C++

Answer (score 0):

> *"...After applying the hue value, the color doesn't resemble what I see in Photoshop."*

Your code assumes `+50` hue value to mean jumping near to **120** degrees (gives Greens), but Photoshop only goes **half that distance** to land near **60** degrees (gives Yellows).

You can see that on an R-G-B colour wheel, Red always starts at **0** degrees.

Looking at an example of the "**Reds**" in your **input** image, you can see that the model's hair and jacket have a hue of: **(Red) 0** degrees, now your code does a `+50` hue shift (or colour wheel rotation) which rotates the red dot to be now positioned at **120** degrees, so the old hue Red is now replaced by a new hue of: **(Green) 120**.

***PS:*** 
Your Greens have a strong hint of Yellow so I suspect you are actually landing in the *90 to 100* degree area.

[image]

**Whats going on here?** Let's investigate the docs...

> ***`COLOR_BGR2HSV`***
> *Convert RGB/BGR into HSV (hue saturation value)*
> *with **H range 0..180** if 8 bit image.*

Son of a... So they really mapped **360** degrees into **180** levels? Yes, crazy but true.

```
( 360 / 180 ) * 50 hue factor = 100 degrees on the colour wheel
```

*(note: There is a **360/255** option called `COLOR_BGR2HSV_FULL` so they are trying to be helpful within the limits)*.

**Two Possible Solution(s)**:

**(1)** Fix at the input **reading** side:

You can counter the above equation with:

```
( 180 / 360 ) * 50 hue factor = 25 degrees on the colour wheel
```

Where: In color, the code's resulting **25** degrees should match the Photoshop result at its `+50` hue offsetting.

*(untested example, no C++ compiler here):*

```
int hue = 0; //# hue of input pixel
int hueFactor = 50; //# factor for adding

//# using either Float or Int to store a "difference" offset between Photoshop and OpenCV values
int hue_coeff_PShop = 2; //# is "divide by 2 to match Photoshop" value for same point in colour wheel.
float hue_coeff_PShop = 0.5f; //# is ( OpenCV_180 / PShop_360 ) == using 0.5 as multiplication co-effecient

//# (1) Loop through the rows
for (int y = 0; y < outputImage.rows; ++y) 
{
    //# Loop through the columns
    for (int x = 0; x < outputImage.cols; ++x) 
    {
        //# Retrieve the current pixel and extract its current hue value
        cv::Vec3b &pixelValue = outputImage.at<cv::Vec3b>(y,x);
        hue = static_cast<int>( pixelValue[0] );

        //# Adjust the hue value using ADD with hueFactor (then doing MINUS is another option)
        hue += static_cast<int>( hueFactor * hue_coeff_PShop ); //# same as... ( hueFactor * 0.5f );
        
        //# Ensure the hue value wraps around correctly within the 0-179 range
        if (hue > 180) { hue -= 180; }
        
        pixelValue[0] = static_cast<uchar>(hue);
    }
}
```

**(2)** Or Else.. Fix at the output **writing** side:

So you have green output, how can you still match Photoshop with these green pixels?

You can try **ADD**ing the two images together. This means:

You need two arrays (or vectors) each of length 3, that is one to hold the Input's R-G-B and the other holds the Output's R-G-B.

Add 50% from each side's related component. 
The new result should match (or be close) to the Photoshop output.

Some pseudo-code:

```
//# add each side together (do reds, greens, blues separately): 
new_Red = ( ( in_R * 0.5f ) + ( out_R * 0.5f) ); //# example for red
//new_Grn = ( ( in_G * 0.5f ) + ( out_G * 0.5f) ); //# other example for green

//# then clamp the sum if it is above 255:
if( new_Red > 255 ) { new_Red = 255; } //# example for red
//if( new_Grn > 255 ) { new_Grn = 255; } //# other example for green
```